# problem during Qt installation

Tags: qt4

I'm currently downloading Qt4 and I got to about 85% of the download, when an unexpected error message popped up, saying...

> Error during installation
>   process(com.nokia.ndk.tools.simulator.qtgcc):
>   Error while relocating Qt: Can't start
>   process install_name_tool.

What should I do? I'm not sure what the problem is.

EDIT: I'm downloading this on the snow leopard operating system and I've tried the online installer and the full package download.

Comment: 1. I think it would be helpful to specify which Operating System you are using (Linux, Mac OS X, ...?) 2. Try to be more specific about what you have already attempted to deal with the problem (Have you tried downloading the full package instead of the online installer? Does the problem still occur?) :-) Good Luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All you need to do is install GCC - that comes with Xcode ! I had the same issues Lion, I installed gcc, and reinstalled QT... things went smooth. to double check if you have the same issues, use " which gcc" and see if you have gcc.

To install gcc, go to Xcode->Preference->Downloads and click install button besides "Command line tools".

Comment: Even adding command line tools didn't solve problem for me :(
I'm using Lion with XCode 4.3 as a single app file. + I installed Command line tools

Comment: My problem is Error during installation process (org.kde.necessitas.android.qt.armeabi):
Error while relocating Qt: Can't start process install_name_tool.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled xcode (from the apple developer website) and selected all the options that come with the package this time. I had no more problems during the installation.