# I can no longer build and run in Xcode 3

Tags: c++, xcode, build, g++

I checked to see if the terminal recognized g++/gcc and it did, but I can't build and run in xcode. Every time I try to do it I get this...

[image: Xcode build results]

Xcode used to build and run properly on my computer and then I reinstalled xcode to get some extra features that I didn't have (iOS SDK). Also, I wanted to fix this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436583/problem-during-qt-installation).

Before this problem, I had an alternate problem where I had already 2 versions of xcode on my computer, and I had to change my .bash_profile to this to fix the problem (g++/gcc not recognized in terminal)

```
export PATH=$PATH:$M2 
export PATH=/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}
export MANPATH=/Developer/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}
```

Comment: Do you have Xcode 4 installed?

Comment: Did you recently did an OS X update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have a gcc-4.2 and  g++-4.2 in `/Developer/usr/bin`. Instead I had i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2 and i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2 and a bunch of other similar files, which I thought were the same thing as gcc-4.2/g++4.2. Apparently I could still compile and run in the shell with this, but Xcode needed those specific files. I just searched for gcc-4.2/g++4.2 using finder and I copied and pasted the files into `/Developer/usr/bin`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

So what happened to /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2? Did you uninstall it, but not reinstall? Have you checked what version of gcc you have installed? Can you run gcc from the shell?

Comment: Yes, I can run gcc from the shell and I have multiple versions installed (4.0 and 4.2). I didn't uninstall at all. I just went to the apple developers site and downloaded xcode 3 and check marked all the boxes in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your *project* won't build, or XCode is unable to make a new project?

When upgrading XCode versions, a lot of project settings become problematic, especially path settings as XCode installer "cleans out" old SDKs without telling you.

You might want to create a new empty project and move your source files over to it.

Comment: I mean my project won't build. I tried creating a new xcode project and it did that successfully, but I cannot build the project. Is there a way to configure path settings? Or, check if the path settings are right? I know for sure I have gcc in that file directory.