# Qt SDK installation fails - com.nokia.ndk.api.qtcomponents.simulator.gcc Can't start process install_name_tool

Tags: macos, qt, installation

I am trying to install the Qt SDK on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8, with XCode version 3.2.6.  During the install I get the following error:

> Error during installation process
>   (com.nokia.ndk.api.qtcomponents.simulator.gcc): Can't start process
>   install_name_tool.

What do I do to get this to install correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be answered here : [problem during Qt installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436583/problem-during-qt-installation)

It would appear that GCC is not included with the xcode app. Free registration as an Apple Developer allows you to download the command line tools as follows:
Xcode->Preference->Downloads and click install button besides "Command line tools".

After installing gcc, reinstall QT, and those messages should no longer appear